# Factorial method- logical error in java recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         factorial(5);      
    }

    public static void factorial(int n)
    {
        int fact=n;
        if(n>0)
        {

        fact =n*n-1;
        n=n-2;
        factorial(n);
        System.out.println("Factorial is: "+fact);      
        }
    }
```

I have the following out put:
Factorial is: 0
Factorial is: 8
Factorial is: 24
but factorial of 5 should be 120
I have following questions:

1. How recursion works here
2. how to fix the logical problem

Answer (score 0):

You can find several answers online,
Your answer is wrong.Ist there is a logical error in fact =n*n-1;

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int result;

   if(n==1)
     return 1;

   result = fact(n-1) * n;
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {

    static int fact = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         factorial(5);      
    }

    public static void factorial(int n)
    {

        if(n>0) {

            fact = fact * (n);
            factorial(n-1);
        } else {

            System.out.println("Factorial is: "+fact);
        }

    }
}
```